# Can you use LINQ types and extension methods in IronPython?

Tags: linq, ironpython

Is it possible to use the LINQ types and extension methods in IronPython?

If so how? And also is there often more pythonic to do the same thing?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

IronPython 2.7 finally bridges this gap with the `clr.ImportExtensions` method which adds the extension methods from a namespace to the target types e.g.

```
>& 'C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\ipy.exe'
IronPython 2.7 (2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.225
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import clr
>>> clr.AddReference("System.Core")
>>> from System.Collections.Generic import List
>>> dir (List)
['Add', 'AddRange', 'AsReadOnly', 'BinarySearch', 'Capacity', 'Clear', 'Contains', 'ConvertAll', 'CopyTo', 'Count', 'Enu
merator', 'Equals', 'Exists', 'Find', 'FindAll', 'FindIndex', 'FindLast', 'FindLastIndex', 'ForEach', 'GetEnumerator', '
GetHashCode', 'GetRange', 'GetType', 'IndexOf', 'Insert', 'InsertRange', 'IsReadOnly', 'IsSynchronized', 'Item', 'LastIn
dexOf', 'MemberwiseClone', 'ReferenceEquals', 'Remove', 'RemoveAll', 'RemoveAt', 'RemoveRange', 'Reverse', 'Sort', 'Sync
Root', 'ToArray', 'ToString', 'TrimExcess', 'TrueForAll', '__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc_
_', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__new__', '__reduce
__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
>>> import System
>>> clr.ImportExtensions(System.Linq)
>>> dir (List)
['Add', 'AddRange', 'Aggregate', 'All', 'Any', 'AsEnumerable', 'AsParallel', 'AsQueryable', 'AsReadOnly', 'Average', 'Bi
narySearch', 'Capacity', 'Cast', 'Clear', 'Concat', 'Contains', 'ConvertAll', 'CopyTo', 'Count', 'DefaultIfEmpty', 'Dist
inct', 'ElementAt', 'ElementAtOrDefault', 'Enumerator', 'Equals', 'Except', 'Exists', 'Find', 'FindAll', 'FindIndex', 'F
indLast', 'FindLastIndex', 'First', 'FirstOrDefault', 'ForEach', 'GetEnumerator', 'GetHashCode', 'GetRange', 'GetType',
'GroupBy', 'GroupJoin', 'IndexOf', 'Insert', 'InsertRange', 'Intersect', 'IsReadOnly', 'IsSynchronized', 'Item', 'Join',
 'Last', 'LastIndexOf', 'LastOrDefault', 'LongCount', 'Max', 'MemberwiseClone', 'Min', 'OfType', 'OrderBy', 'OrderByDesc
ending', 'ReferenceEquals', 'Remove', 'RemoveAll', 'RemoveAt', 'RemoveRange', 'Reverse', 'Select', 'SelectMany', 'Sequen
ceEqual', 'Single', 'SingleOrDefault', 'Skip', 'SkipWhile', 'Sort', 'Sum', 'SyncRoot', 'Take', 'TakeWhile', 'ToArray', '
ToDictionary', 'ToList', 'ToLookup', 'ToString', 'TrimExcess', 'TrueForAll', 'Union', 'Where', 'Zip', '__add__', '__clas
s__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__hash__', '__init__',
 '__iter__', '__len__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__'
, '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
>>>
```

which brings it into line with IronRuby 1.1's `using_clr_extensions` method.

Answer (score 24):

Some of the things you'd do with LINQ can be done with list comprehensions:

```
[myFunc(i) for i in numbers if i > 3]
```

Or you can use `map`, `reduce`, and `filter`:

```
map(myFunc, filter(lambda x: x > 3, numbers))
```

But list comprehensions are much more "Pythonic" than using the functional programming constructs. For reducing things, consider using `"".join` or `sum`. And you can check the truth value of entire iterables by using `any` and `all`.

Just remember these translations:

```
Select -> map
Where -> filter
Aggregate -> reduce
```

And you'll be well on your way!

Answer (score 16):

In [IronPython 2.7.1](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/62475) you have *clr.ImportExtensions* for this use case.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Core")
import System
clr.ImportExtensions(System.Linq)

# will print 3 and 4 :)
[2, 3, 4].Where(lambda x: x != 2).ToList().ForEach(System.Console.WriteLine)
```

A little background: [IronPython 2.7](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/54498) initially introduced this feature, but there was [an issue](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/30379) which stopped it from being really usable.

Answer (score 3):

I [described a C# wrapper class](http://jeroen.haegebaert.com/post/2010/07/24/Chained-method-syntax-in-IronPython-(alternative-to-extension-methods)) around the LINQ extension methods to achieve a syntax similar to C#'s 'chained extension method' syntax in IronPython.

The idea is to have a kind of decorator class around `IEnumerable` that simply calls the extension methods. Probably this wrapper class can be written just as well in IronPython, but I'm not as fluent in Python yet :-)

```cs
public class ToLinq<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> _wrapped;

    public ToLinq(IEnumerable<T> wrapped)
    {
       _wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    public ToLinq<T> Where(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return new ToLinq<T>(_wrapped.Where(predicate));
    }

    // ... similar methods for other operators like Select, Count, Any, ...
}
```

This allows for a syntax similar to this:

```py
johns = ToLinq[Customer](customers)\
          .Where(lambda c: c.Name.StartsWith("John"))\
          .Select(lambda c: c.Name)
```

Disclaimer: This is something I tried as a learning exercise. I haven't used this in a real-world project.